# Can adding two numbers increase the significant figures?

Tags: error-analysis

I am having a question regarding significant figures in calculating average of two masses. For example adding two masses 7 kg and 8 kg gives 15 kg, both inputs 7 and 8 have only one significant figure but final answer 15 has two significant figures.

Now if I take average of the masses 15/2 gives 7.5, (Note: the number 2 has infinite significant figures because it represent a whole quantity, so it is 2.0000... in actual)

Hence the calculated average 7.5 kg has two significant figures obtained from the sum 15 kg (which has 2 significant figures and it determines the significant figure of the result of division)

Is this logic correct? Can addition (or taking average) increase the significant figure of the result? Can I write my final average as 7.5 kg or should I write only 8 kg (after rounding off 7.5 to one significant figure because both inputs have only one significant figure)?

Thank you for your help in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question which was asked was *Can adding two numbers increase the significant figures?*
In this context the question is misleading in that when values range over a value of . . . . . $0.1$ or $1$ or $10$ . . . . etc the use of the term **significant** figures can give a false impression.
The accuracy of the value $9.99$ is not really any different from the accuracy of the value $10.01$ even though the second value is quoted to four figures whilst the first value is quoted to only three figures.

It is not clear if the quoted masses, $7\,\rm kg$ and $8\,\rm kg$,  are actually more accurate than the one figure quoted.  For example you might expect a hanger mass that is found in the laboratory with a label of $100\,\rm g$ on it to be accurate to at least $\pm 0.1\,\rm g$.

Suppose that the device which measured these two masses was graduated in $1\,\rm kilogramme$ steps and so any mass between $6.5\dot0 \,\rm kg$ and $7.4\dot9\,\rm kg$ is registered as being of mass $7\,\rm kg$ but note that there are measuring devices where the range for a reading of $7\,\rm kg$ might be $7.\dot0\,\rm kg$ to $7.\dot 9\,\rm kg$.

Thus the mass of $7\,\rm kg$ could have a mass between $6.5\,\,\rm kg$ and $7.5\,\,\rm kg$ and the mass of $8\,\rm kg$ could have a mass between $7.5\,\,\rm kg$ and $8.5\,\,\rm kg$.
When these two masses are combined one could say that the combined mass is $15\,\rm kg$ with a range between $14\,\rm kg$ and $16\,\rm kg$.
In practice this range would probable be an overestimate as the likelihood of both masses being on the very light side (eg $6.5$ and $7.5$) or both masses being on the very heavy side ($7.5$ and $8.5$) is not as great as the masses being closer to their stated values and possibly one lighter and the other heavier
Perhaps then a better estimator of the error in the sum is $\pm\sqrt{0.5^2 + 0.5^2} \approx \pm 0.7\,\rm kg$ with the percentage error for the sum being smaller than the percentage error for the individual masses.

The question which was asked was *Can adding two numbers increase the significant figures?*
In this context the question is misleading in that when values range over a value of . . . . . $0.1$ or $1$ or $10$ . . . . etc the use of the term **significant** figures can give a false impression as the accuracy of the value $9.99$ is not really any different from the accuracy of the value $10.01$ even though the second value is quoted to four figures whilst the first value is only quoted to three figures.

Answer (score 3):

Consider what the number of significant figures indicates:

The number written as $7$ has $1$ significant figure;  the number is somewhere between $6.5$ and $7.5$

The number written as $8$ has $1$ significant figure;  the number is somewhere between $7.5$ and $8.5$

So, when you add these two numbers;$$7+8=15$$

the answer, $15$, lies somewhere between $6.5+7.5 =14$, and $7.5+8.5 =16$

$15  ± 1$ is not two significant figures...

Comment: Basically correct, but a more sophisticated treatment of the experimental errors would get a somewhat different estimate of the final error.